# How can I change the value of key of array base on another key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this variable which is the result of my query:

```
Array(
       [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 1
             [visibility] => 0
         )

       [2] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2
             [visibility] => 1
         )

       [3] => Array
         (
             [id] => 3
             [visibility] => 0
         )
)
```

Now I want to change the number of `[id]` item when its `[visibility]` is `0`. For example I want to append `00` in the beginning of the number of `[id]`. This is expected output:

```
Array(
       [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 001
             [visibility] => 0
         )

       [2] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2
             [visibility] => 1
         )

       [3] => Array
         (
             [id] => 003
             [visibility] => 0
         )
)
```

How can I do that?

---

I can check the value of `visibility` like this:

```
foreach ($var as $item) {
    if ($item['visibility'] == 0) {
        // I need to append two zero before the number of its id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started `foreach` and correct condition check but didn't write any code inside it. Check below:-

```
   <?php
    foreach ($var as $key=> $item) {
        if ($item['visibility'] == 0) { // if visibility is 0
            $var[$key]['id'] = "00". $var[$key]['id']; // add 00 to corresponding id in the original array
        }
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($var);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly easier to reference `$item` and change it:

```
foreach ($var as &$item) {
    if ($item['visibility'] == 0) {
        $item['id'] = "00{$item['id']}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Reference yes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php  There is also an example at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: `$item` is a reference `&` to each array in `$var`, so it works yes.

Comment: What's `{}` in `00{$item['id']}`?

Comment: Used for complex vars in double-quotes as just `$item['id']` will not work.